# How to add line between two rows of nodes in Tikz and how to align nodes vertically?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two questions:

1. How can I add a horizontal line centered between two rows of nodes in Tikz?
2. How can I change the vertical placement of a node to line up better with other nodes

A picture of what I mean will make this clearer:

[image]

The blue line indicates the line I'd like to add (it should be straight of course). Note the two red circles. Because of the subscripts the arrows don't "hit" them in the center of the `X` like it does for `X_1, X_2, X_3`. So how can I move these down somewhat?

Here's a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m)[matrix of nodes, column  sep=1cm,row  sep=8mm, nodes={draw=none, anchor=center} ]{
\node [] {$X_1$}; & \node [] {$X_2$}; & \node [] {$X_3$}; & \node [] {$\ldots$}; & \node [] {$X_{\frac{n}{8}-1}$}; & \node [] {$X_{\frac{n}{8}}$}; \\
\node [] {$Y_1$}; & \node [] {$Y_2$}; & \node [] {$Y_3$}; & \node [] {$\ldots$}; & \node [] {$Y_{\frac{n}{8}-1}$}; & \node [] {$Y_{\frac{n}{8}}$}; \\
};

\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-1) edge node [above] {$\ast$} (m-1-2);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-2) edge (m-2-2);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-2) edge (m-2-3);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-3) edge node [above] {$\ast$} (m-1-2);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-3) edge node [above] {$\ast$} (m-1-4);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-4) edge (m-2-5);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-5) edge node [above] {$\ast$} (m-1-4);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-5) edge node [above] {$\ast$} (m-1-6);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-6) edge (m-2-6);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simplify the syntax by using `matrix of math nodes` option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains, calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes, column  sep=1cm,row  sep=8mm, nodes={draw=none, anchor=center,text depth=0pt} ]{
X_1 & X_2 & X_3 &\ldots & X_{\frac{n}{8}-1} & X_{\frac{n}{8}} \\
Y_1 & Y_2 & Y_3 &\ldots & Y_{\frac{n}{8}-1} & Y_{\frac{n}{8}} \\
};

\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-1) edge node [above] {$\ast$} (m-1-2);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-2) edge (m-2-2);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-2) edge (m-2-3);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-3) edge node [above] {$\ast$} (m-1-2);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-3) edge node [above] {$\ast$} (m-1-4);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-4) edge (m-2-5);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-5) edge node [above] {$\ast$} (m-1-4);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-5) edge node [above] {$\ast$} (m-1-6);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-6) edge (m-2-6);
\draw[shorten <=-1cm,shorten >=-1cm] ($(m-1-1)!0.5!(m-2-1)$)--($(m-1-6)!0.5!(m-2-6)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It might look better without the `anchor=center` (since then it defaults to `anchor=base` for `matrix of math nodes`) and using the `mid west`, `mid east` anchors on the arrows.

Comment: @AndrewStacey That's probably the way to go. Today somehow, I'm not thinking straight.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the code even more clean by using `every path` and `every node`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains, calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes, column  sep=1cm,row  sep=8mm, nodes={draw=none, anchor=center,text depth=0pt} ]{
X_1 & X_2 & X_3 &\ldots & X_{\frac{n}{8}-1} & X_{\frac{n}{8}} \\
Y_1 & Y_2 & Y_3 &\ldots & Y_{\frac{n}{8}-1} & Y_{\frac{n}{8}} \\
};

\tikzstyle{every path}=[>=latex,->]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[above]
\path (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1)
  (m-1-1) edge node {$\ast$} (m-1-2)
  (m-1-2) edge (m-2-2)
  (m-1-2) edge (m-2-3)
  (m-1-3) edge node {$\ast$} (m-1-2)
  (m-1-3) edge node {$\ast$} (m-1-4)
  (m-1-4) edge (m-2-5)
  (m-1-5) edge node {$\ast$} (m-1-4)
  (m-1-5) edge node {$\ast$} (m-1-6)
  (m-1-6) edge (m-2-6);
\draw[shorten <=-1cm,shorten >=-1cm,>=] ($(m-1-1)!0.5!(m-2-1)$)--($(m-1-6)!0.5!(m-2-6)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```