# Drawing network protocols

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, engineering

I want to produce network protocols, a very simplified example of which is depicted below:

[image: A simple protocol]

The protocol has two parties, each of which does some computation and then communicated with the other.

I can use a 3-column table, but I want to know if there is any better solution. Especially, whether there is any particular package for this, or any simple way to do it in TikZ.

Comment: Don't you think the image is a little too sparse? Visually it doesn't convey the message that the time is going downwards. I think the arrows need to have a target and a source. Of course I have no idea what are the specific practices of your field but still it can be a little intuitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my simple solution using [the method shown here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53931/how-to-add-line-between-two-rows-of-nodes-in-tikz-and-how-to-align-nodes-vertica):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains, calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m)[matrix of nodes, column  sep=2cm,row  sep=8mm, nodes={draw=none, anchor=center,text depth=0pt} ]{
Prover & & Verifier\\[-4mm]
Choose a random number & & \\[-7mm]
$r \in \{0,1\}^{*}.$ & & \\
 & Send $r$ & \\
& & Choose a random number  \\[-7mm]
& &$s \in \{0,1\}^{*}.$\\
 & Send $s$ & \\
};

\draw[shorten <=-1.5cm,shorten >=-1.5cm] (m-1-1.south east)--(m-1-1.south west);
\draw[shorten <=-1.5cm,shorten >=-1.5cm] (m-1-3.south east)--(m-1-3.south west);
\draw[shorten <=-1cm,shorten >=-1cm,-latex] (m-4-2.south west)--(m-4-2.south east);
\draw[shorten <=-1cm,shorten >=-1cm,-latex] (m-7-2.south east)--(m-7-2.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** The graphical result is:

[image]

Comment: It's always nice to have an image of the result. The `standalone` class or `pdfcrop` can help here. It is recommended to convert it to a PNG yourself before uploading. You can use `\documentclass[png]{standalone}` and then compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape` (needs Image Magic to be installed).

Answer (score 8):

Did you look at [MSC (Message Sequence Charts) package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/msc)  in CTAN? I've never used but some of our students did it.

**EDIT** Your example could be done with some code like this

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{msc}
\begin{document}
\begin{msc}{Example}
\declinst{prover}{}{Prover}
\declinst{verifier}{}{Verifier}
\action*{%
\begin{minipage}{3cm}\centering 
Choose a random number\\
$r\in\{0,1\}^*$
\end{minipage}%
}{prover}
\nextlevel[4]
\mess{Send $r$}{prover}{verifier}
\nextlevel
\action*{%
\begin{minipage}{3cm}\centering
Choose a random number\\
$r\in\{0,1\}^*$
\end{minipage}}{verifier}
\nextlevel[4]
\mess{Send $s$}{verifier}{prover}
\end{msc}
\end{document}
```

and the result (with xelatex because msc uses pstricks) is

[image]

The apperance is not so flexible because msc diagrams are normalized by [ITU](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-Z.120/en) (International Telecomunication Union) and the package respects the format.

Comment: When I try to run your example I run into an undefined control sequence: `\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks     _Not_Configured_For_This_Format`.

Comment: @lucidbrot I've tested again and it works without problems. Did you use `xelatex` to compile it? Do you use an updated TeX system?

Comment: Thanks for testing! I've tried on two systems - one with texLive and one with MikTex. At least the latter one I completely reinstalled. But no, I did not run it with `xelatex` but with `pdflatex`. I have now tried again using `xelatex` and it failed again. But running it a second time with `xelatex` without any changes made it work. So... I guess I'll have to read up what the difference between `pdflatex` and `xelatex` is.