# How to draw communication based diagram in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want draw such a diagram. Is there any tikz package for drawing such thing?
Is there any example tex code for the same? How do I draw such diagrams?

[image]

I have tried drawing it. My tex code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning}
\usepackage{scalefnt}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
[my shape/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1, draw}]
\tikzset{input/.style={}}

\draw (0,0)--++(0,-10cm);
\draw (5,0)--++(0,-10cm);

\draw[->] (0,-1) coordinate (a) -- 
node [near end,sloped, above=2mm,my shape=2, rectangle split horizontal]    (n3) {0\nodepart{two}$m_0$}
node [left=3 cm of n3,sloped,above=2mm,my shape=2, rectangle split horizontal]  (n4) {0\nodepart{two}$m_0$}
++(5,-.5) coordinate (b);

\node [left =1mm of a,my shape=2, rectangle split horizontal] (n1) {0\nodepart{two}$m_0$};
\coordinate [below=1mm of b] (c) ;

\node [right=1mm of c, my shape=2, rectangle split horizontal] (n3)  {0\nodepart{two}$m_0$};
\coordinate [below=1mm of c] (d);
\draw[->] (d) -- ++(-5,-.5);

\path (a)--node[cross out,draw=red]{} (b);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I am getting something like this :
[image]

**I want to have nodes above the arrow to be at the same distance from vertical lines. How do I do that?**

Any help?

Comment: I want the rectangle boxes to float with arrow. Any tex code?

Comment: This question is too broad in its current form, you can't just post an image and say "I need to draw this". Take a look at [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net), the [pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf) or some of the [tag:tikz-pgf] questions on this site to get started, and edit the question to be more concrete if you get stuck.

Comment: I think you can even refer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54006/drawing-network-protocols/54009#54009) as starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a possible solution. Tikz is so flexible that you will find some more. 
What I've done is first draw the vertical lines and use them to place nodes on the left and right side. In fact I've drawn first arrow and name starting and finishing coordinates a and b. Paquet nodes are placed relative to a and b. Hope you could understand the code.

If your red beam means a broken link or some transmission problem I prefer to use some symbol over the link. In this example I've used a `cross out` node.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning}
\usepackage{scalefnt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[my shape/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1, draw}]
\tikzset{input/.style={}}

\draw (0,0)--++(0,-10cm);
\draw (4,0)--++(0,-10cm);

\draw[->] (0,-.5) coordinate (a) -- 
node [near end,sloped, above=2mm,my shape=2, rectangle split horizontal] (n3) {0\nodepart{two}$m_0$}
++(4,-.5) coordinate (b);

\node [left =1mm of a,my shape=2, rectangle split horizontal] (n1) {0\nodepart{two}$m_0$};

\node [right=1mm of b, my shape=2, rectangle split horizontal] (n2)  {0\nodepart{two}$m_0$};

\draw[->,red] (b) -- ++(-4,-.5);

\path (a)--node[cross out,draw=red]{} (b);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) One doubt : How to put nodes above the arrow at same angle such that it looks good?

Comment: @user1280282: Just add option `sloped` to node options list.

Comment: I have edited my question. I have one more doubt.

Comment: @user1280282: as Peter Grill suggested in your other question, use `pos=0.7` instead of `near end`. In fact `near end`, `near start`, ... are particular replacements for `pos=...`