# Adding circled numbers to beginning of the arrow using tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing, tikz-arrows

I would like to draw something similar to the following image using `tikzpicture`. I succeed in drawing the arrows but I could not put numbers at the beginning of them. 
I used the idea in [Drawing network protocols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54006/drawing-network-protocols) to draw the arrows.

Can you help me about it? Thanks!

Below you can see what I have done.
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\tiny]
\matrix (m)[matrix of nodes, column  sep=2cm,row  sep=8mm, nodes={draw=none, anchor=center,text depth=0pt} ]{
{\normalsize \textbf{$ P_i $}} & $ (pk,v,g, \Z_p, t_1, t_2, id) $ and names of parties are public  & {\normalsize \textbf{$ P_j $}}\\[-4mm]
$ x_i\in_r \Z_p $ & & $ x_j\in_r \Z_p$ \\[-7mm]
& $h_i=g^{x_i}$, $ PK log(g,h)\{\xi: h=g^{\xi}\} $ & \\
$ h = \sum g^{x_i} = g^x $ & $h_j=g^{x_j}$, $ PK log(g,h)\{\xi: h=g^{\xi}\} $ &   $    h = \sum g^{x_i} = g^x $ \\
& \textbf{. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .} & \\

$ r_i \in \Z_p $  & $ V^1_i = VE((g^{r_i},s_ih^{r_i}), h;\emptyset)\{(v_i,s_i)\in R\} $ & 

\\ };

\draw[shorten <=-1cm,shorten >=-1cm] (m-1-1.south east)--(m-1-1.south west){};
\draw[shorten <=-1cm,shorten >=-1cm] (m-1-3.south east)--(m-1-3.south west);
\draw[shorten <=-1cm,shorten >=-1cm,-latex] (m-3-2.south west)--(m-3-2.south east);
\draw[shorten <=-1cm,shorten >=-1cm,-latex](m-4-2.south east)--(m-4-2.south west);

\draw[shorten <=-1cm,shorten >=-1cm,-latex] (m-6-2.south west)--(m-6-2.south east);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I add what I did

Comment: @user1914367: the best approach would be to add a couple of columns (one at the beginning and one at the end) of the matrix in which you could put numbers (i.e. `|[circle,inner sep=1pt]|1`). BTW: welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Yes I tried it, but in this case the numbers looks far from the arrows. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use nodes directly. Here is a solution which mimics your diagram, using temporary nodes to place the elements relatively to each other :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{empty node}=[draw=none, inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt]
  \tikzstyle{arrow start}=[draw, circle, inner sep = 1pt]

  %move these node to modify the width of the diagram
  \draw[draw=none]
    (0,0) %set here the start x position for arrows
    node (startPos) {}
    ++(-1,0) node[empty node] (dashedStartPos) {} %set here the left dash offset
    (10,0) %set here the end x position for arrows
    node (endPos) {}
    ++( 1,0) node[empty node] (dashedEndPos) {} %set here the right dash offset
  ;

  \draw (dashedStartPos) node {Alice} ;
  \draw (dashedEndPos) node {Bob} ;

  %left to right arrow
  \newcommand{\leftToRight}[4][tmp]{
    \draw[-latex]
      (startPos) ++(0,#2) 
      node[arrow start] (#1 1) {#3}
      (endPos) ++(0,#2)
      node[empty node] (#1 2) {}
      (#1 1)
      -- node[midway, above] {#4}
      (#1 2)
    ;
  }

  %right to left arrow
  \newcommand{\rightToLeft}[4][tmp]{
    \draw[-latex]
      (endPos) ++(0,#2) 
      node[arrow start] (#1 2) {#3}
      (startPos) ++(0,#2)
      node[empty node] (#1 1) {}
      (#1 2)
      -- node[midway, above] {#4}
      (#1 1)
    ;
  }

  %dashed line
  \newcommand{\dashedLine}[1]{
    \draw[dashed]
      (dashedStartPos) ++(0,#1)
      node[empty node] (tmp1) {}
      (dashedEndPos) ++(0,#1)
      node[empty node] (tmp2) {}
      (tmp1) -- (tmp2)
    ;
  }

  %example diagram
  %arrows
  \leftToRight{-1}{1}{arrow 1}
  \rightToLeft{-2}{2}{arrow 2}
  %dashed line
  \dashedLine{-3}
  %more arrows
  \rightToLeft[loopStart]{-4}{4}{arrow 3}
  \leftToRight{-5}{1}{arrow 6}
  \rightToLeft{-6}{2}{arrow 7}
  \leftToRight[loopEnd]{-7}{5}{arrow 8}

  %side note
  \draw[draw = none]
    (startPos)
    -- node[midway] (notePos) {}
    (dashedStartPos)
    (loopEnd 1)
    -| node[midway] (noteStart) {}
    (notePos)
    (loopStart 1)
    -| node[midway] (noteEnd) {}
    (notePos)
  ;
  \draw[-latex]
    (noteStart) -- ++(-5mm,0) 
    |- node[pos = 0.25, text width=2cm, left, text centered] {
      repeat for multiple files
    }
    (noteEnd)
  ;


\end{tikzpicture}
```

And the output

[image]