# Network communication flowchart with requests and answers (HTTP flow or SIP flow)

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I want to create a flowchart for network communication between user and server similar to example below:
[image: Example network communication flowchart]

I've searched for similar flowcharts on TikZ examples page, but only things that seems someway similar were matrix charts. At the end matrix charts don't look very similar to the end effect I want to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). This isn't a "Please do my work for me" site! What do you have so far? Try to create ...

Comment: You can use `msc` package (msc: message sequence charts). You'll have to use xelatex. An example:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54390/1952

Comment: Look at the tutorials at the start of the Ti*k*Z manual. It is just a couple of rectangles and a few arrows, after all. Nothing complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code could be prettier, but the outcome is what you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2cm,tikz]{standalone}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
%\tikzset{every picture/.style=thick}
every node/.append style={very thick,rounded corners=0.1mm}
]

\node[draw,rectangle] (User) at (0,0) {User};

\node[draw,rectangle] (Server) at (3,0) {Server};

\node[draw=blue!50,rectangle,thick] (Network) at (0,-1) {Network Attach};

\draw [very thick] (User)  --  (Network)--(0,-5);
\draw [very thick] (Server)--++(0,-5);

\draw [->,very thick] (0,-2)--node [auto] {HTTP GET}++(3,0);
\draw [<-,very thick] (0,-2.5)--node [auto] {200 OK}++(3,0);

\draw [->,very thick] (0,-3.5)--node [auto] {HTTP POST}++(3,0);
\draw [<-,very thick] (0,-4)--node [auto] {200 OK}++(3,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```