# I would like to know how to draw protocol flaw like the following picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I would like to know how to draw protocol flaw like the following picture? I don't know how to draw it exactly.

[image]

Comment: Did you look at any of these?  https://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/sequence-diagram/

Comment: `msc` is a package for this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54390/1952

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not even load any library for that. I would like to argue that it is advantageous to use as few explicit coordinates as possible and then work with relative coordinates and the `pos` syntax in order to arrive at a code in which you can easily add some elements.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw,fill=white,align=center}]
\draw [line width=2mm] (0,0) -- ++(2,0) coordinate[midway](L1)
(6,0) -- ++(2,0) coordinate[midway](R1);
\draw (L1) -- ++ (0,8) 
node[box,pos=0.3] (L1a) {$e=f-\texttt{xcoord}(rY)$\\ $Ee\stackrel{?}{=}P$}
node[box,pos=0.65] (L1b) {$r\in_RZ_\ell^*$}
node[box,pos=1,label=above:{State: $x,Y$}] (L1c) {Tag $T$}
coordinate[pos=0.2] (X1) coordinate[pos=0.55] (X2);
\draw (R1) -- ++ (0,8) 
node[box,pos=0.1] (R1a) {$X=e^{-1}(sP-R)\stackrel{?}{\in}\mathsf{DB}$}
node[box,pos=0.85] (R1b) {$e\in_RZ_\ell^*$}
node[box,pos=1,label=above:{Secrets: $y$~~$\mathsf{DB}:$ $\{X_i\}$}] (R1c) {Reader $T$}
coordinate[pos=0.4] (X3) coordinate[pos=0.75] (X4);
\draw[-latex] (X1) -- (X1 -| R1) node[midway,above]{$s=ex+r$};
\draw[-latex] (X2) -- (X2 -| R1) node[midway,above]{$\mathsf{xcoord}(R)=\mathsf{xcoord}(rP)$};
\draw[-latex] (X3) -- (X3 -| L1) node[midway,above]{$f=\mathsf{xcoord}(yR)+e$};
\draw[-latex] (X4) -- (X4 -| L1) node[midway,above]{$\mathsf{xcoord}(E)=\mathsf{xcoord}(e^{-1}P)$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]